# Webpack - Module build failed when bundling `swc-loader`

Tags: webpack, babel-loader, webpack-5, swc-compiler

I am working on a Webpack tool that can build itself. I am able to build the tool the first time but when I try to rebuild it a second time I get the error `Cannot find module: swc-loader`. The same issue exists when swapping `swc-loader` with `babel-loader`. My hunch is that this is related to webpack's `resolveLoader`

Here is a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/woodpav/webpack5-self-bundler) containing the tool.

Below are the steps to reproduce the issue:

1. Bundle the `src` directory by running `node src/index.js`
2. Bundle the `src` directory again by running `node dist/index.js`

The goal is to be able to run step 2 over and over again.

Answer (score 3):

`swc-loader` is not included in the core lib and needs to be installed via package manager - `yarn install --dev swc-loader`